Prove that if 101 items are distributed among 10 boxes, then at least one of the boxes must contain more than 10 items.
My solution
$$
\text{Let } N_i =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if box } i \text{ contains more than 10 items after all 101 items are distributed}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases} \\
$$
Then,
$$ N = \sum_{x=1}^{10} N_i$$
Is the number of boxes containing more than 10 items. We want to prove that $P(N \geq 1) = 1$.
$$ P(N \geq 1) = 1 - P(N < 1) = 1 - P(N=0)$$
Now $N=0$ if and only if none of the 10 boxes contain more than 10 items, which means all boxes contain 10 or less boxes. This is impossible since from the problem, we have 101 objects to distribute. Thus,
$$ P(N=0) = 0 \rightarrow P(N \geq 1) = 1 - 0 = 1$$
Which is want we wanted to show. Is my reasoning flawed? I feel like it is, but I can't figure out where I made a mistake.
The correct solution is as follow:
Define random variables $X_i, i=1,...,10$ that marks the number of items in box $i$. Observe that,
$$
E(X_i)= \frac{101}{10}
$$
Now suppose that all boxes have $\leq 10$ items in them. Then, we have that
$$
101 = \sum_{i}E(X_i) \leq \sum_{i} 10 = 100
$$
which is a contradiction. So, there has to be a box that has $>10$ items.
Can someone help me understand the reasoning behind their approach, I'm having trouble understanding why this proves that there must be more than 10 items in at least 1 box.
Thank you all!

Why not just say if each box had $10$ items or fewer then there would be only $100$ items or fewer and that would be a contradiction to the given number of items

Forgot to mention this is an exercise from "A first course in probability" by Ross, and the question specifies to "use the probabilistic method to prove this result."

"This is impossible since from the problem, we have 101 objects to distribute" Seems like you are putting the cart before the horse.  If you know this is impossible (which it is, and for your reason) then you don't have to do anything more.  Why prove the probability of the complement of an impossible thing is $1$ when.... you just stated the impossible thing is impossible.

If you are allowed to use expected values I don't see why you have to sum to get the contradiction.  I think it'd be enough to say:  1) Expected value of $X_i$ is $\frac {101}{10}$ but 2) Expected value $\le$ to the maximum given value so if all $X_i \le 10$ $E(X_i) \le 10$.

I understand. Thank you

This has nothing to do with probability, and everything to do with the pigeonhole principle.
The motivation behind the principle is to first ask, what is the maximum number of items that can be placed in each box, such that no box contains more than $10$ items?  Well, that's obviously $10$ items in each box, for a total of $100$ items among all $10$ boxes.
Then you can see that the requirement was that we needed to place $101$ items.  There's one more item left, and it has nowhere else to go.  If you put it in any of the boxes, that box will now contain $11$ items.
Now you might ask, "but why does every box have to contain at least $10$ items?  Before you have to place the $101^{\rm st}$ item, couldn't you arrange them so that some boxes have fewer than $10$?"  Well, if you did that, then one of the boxes will already have more than $10$ items before you place the $101^{\rm st}$.  This is because we already established that the most items you can put in each box without going over $10$ is exactly $10$, and since there are only $10$ boxes, the maximum total items is $100$, which is attained if and only if every box has $10$ items.  Any other arrangement will ensure that at least one box will have more than $10$ items.

Now, to address your specific question regarding the "official solution," the reasoning is as follows.  First, we assume that each ball is randomly distributed with equal probability into any of the $10$ bins, and this distribution is independent of the placement of any other balls.  Then we can see that the average number of balls in each bin is $101/10$, because there are $101$ balls and only $10$ bins.  I think this part of the solution you can agree with.
Next, if we suppose by contradiction that each bin contains at most $10$ balls--i.e., there is no bin with more than $10$ balls--then the average number of balls in each bin cannot be more than $10$; i.e., $$\operatorname{E}[X_i] \le 10.$$  But this contradicts our earlier claim that $\operatorname{E}[X_i] = 101/10 = 10.1$; thus, the assumption that each bin contains at most $10$ balls must be false.  That's the essence of the solution.  The use of summation notation is a bit of an overcomplication, because it is not necessarily true that the balls must be randomly assigned to a bin--in fact, such assignment is not required at all.

Thank you so much for the detailed answer; I now understand why the expected value argument works. A few other problems made a similar argument, and I'm much less confused now. I’ll definitely look into the pigeonhole principle as well.
Note that the question specifies to "use the probabilistic method to prove this result", as it is from Ross's textbook "A First Course in Probability".
